# Make ant design modal resizable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant Design's Modal component, and they don't seem to implement resizability into their modal. I would like to be able to manually resize the modal after it has been opened. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme

You can add your own custom CSS for any component using less.

Answer (score 2):

So what I ended up doing for this was using `react-resizable` and creating a `ResizableBox` within the body of the modal. While not perfect right now, it's definitely something to get me going. Here's a codesandbox where I was doing some tinkering https://codesandbox.io/s/l9y9jrk4ym

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: No.

You can change the preset size in the theme, but not make it dynamically resizable.

Would be pretty tricky to implement on your own I would guess. It is probably simpler to pick another widget (not from Ant Design) which has this feature, such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal-resizable-draggable

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: Yes,using ingenuity

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const ModalView = () => {

    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

    const getWindowDimensions = () => {
       const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window
       return { width, height }
    }

    const useWindowDimensions = () => {
       const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState(getWindowDimensions())

       useEffect(() => {
          const handleResize = () => setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions())

          window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)

          return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)

        }, [])

        return windowDimensions
    }

    const { width } = useWindowDimensions();

    return (
      <Modal
          closable={true}
          centered
          style={{ width: (80 * width / 100), minWidth: (80 * width / 100) }}
          visible={visible}
          onCancel={() => setVisible(false)}
          footer={false}
      >
       /** your component **/
      </Modal>

    )
}
```